# "Стало прохладнее", "похолодало" и "стало холоднее"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

*Хочется разобраться в нюансах смысла и когда какое слово уместнее.*

Если было +32°C и через полчаса стало +31°C, я говорю *"стало холоднее"* как нейтральное, избегая *"стало прохладнее",* которое вроде бы подразумевает, что было уже не жарко. Хотя и первое может вызвать мысли о том, что не очень тепло. То есть *"температура понизилась"* будет безупречным в том плане, что не вызовет ошибочных предположений.

Также и *"похолодало"* строго нейтрально, и похолодать может с +50°C до +45°C, но насколько всё-таки оно уместно без упоминания температур, однако если все знают, что жарко? Неужели остаётся говорить только *"понизилась температура"?*

И действительно ли *"холоднее"* нейтральнее (и уместнее), чем *"прохладнее",* вызывающее обязательные мысли, что уже довольно прохладно (смотрите начало второго абзаца)?

Не знаю почему, но с *"потеплело"* таких проблем я не вижу. Видится так, что только если стоят ужасные холода, как в Сибири или в Антарктике, выражение *"потеплело с -55°C до -50°C"* ещё может вызвать улыбку (хотя и то не обязательно), а если 50 поменять на 20–30, такого уже не возникнет.

Или то, что есть эта разница между *потеплением* и *похолоданием,* это сугубо моё восприятие, а вообще её не должно быть?

Comment: @shampar: а разве надо градусы повторять? Мы же не пишем "от 3 м до 5 м", а только перед вторым числом единицу. И почему без Цельсия нельзя обойтись? Понятно же, что раз я не уточняю, значит, имею в виду шкалу Цельсия — она же именно у нас распространена. На англоязычном сайте надо было бы уточнить, а здесь почему это так необходимо?

Comment: °C — это не просто единица измерения, а особый знак. Тот способ записи интервала, о котором говорите, возможен с заменой °C на град.

Comment: @shampar: а чем плохо было просто со значком градуса? И почему такой способ возможен только с "град."? Я могу, конечно, поверить, но всё-таки хочется понять, кто так рекомендует.

Comment: Можно всяко. Просто «°» не говорит о том, какой именно градус. Символ полный (°C) снимает вопрос в любом тексте, а в таком, как у Вас — не техническом — «град» более подходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полностью с Вами согласна, что

> "температура понизилась" будет безупречным в том плане, что не
>   вызовет ошибочных предположений.

Стало холоднее, захолодало, захолодело, похолодало,  стало прохладнее - это синонимы (в «Словаре синонимов» ASIS.В.Н. Тришин.2013). https://rus-synonim-dict.slovaronline.com/330501-%D1%81%D1%

Все слова с корнем холод передают состояние холодной или прохладной погоды.

> ПРОХЛАДА, ы, жен. Приятный холодок, свежесть. Летняя утренняя п.
>   Повеяло прохладой.
>
> Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова. 1949 1992 …

А если +31°C, это не "стало холоднее" (никак не нейтральное) и не "стало прохладнее" - какая же свежесть при  +31°C?

Вот примеры прогнозов погоды:

> •  Дневная температура воздуха после наблюдавшихся 35-40 градусов жары  понизится до 20-30 градусов.
>
> •  Expert.ru 21 августа в 20:39
>
> Прогноз погоды: Гидрометцентр и МЧС предупреждают о наступлении очень  сильной жары. Почти всю следующую неделю также будет стоять  тропическая жара, а температурный фон понизится всего на несколько  градусов.
>
> • РИА Оренбуржье 21 августа в 08:28
>
> В Оренбуржье начинает спадать жара
>   - Температурный режим сбавит свои обороты тридцатиградусной жары и немного понизится, однако это не повлияет на чрезвычайную пожарную  опасность в восточных районах области...

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! А согласны, что у "потеплело" шире диапазон?

Comment: Может быть, но потеплеть может после холодной погоды, а у нас жара. Тоже не пойдёт.

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к ответу Людмилы. Вообще собирался так же ответить.

Прохладно - слегка холодно.

Такие сравнения подразумевают следующее:
Стало холоднее = стало более холодно. То есть раньше было холодно, а теперь ещё холоднее. Если температура была +30°C, а стала +5°C, то лучше сказать "стало холодно" - незачем сравнивать, ведь раньше холодно не было. Само слово "стало" уже подразумевает изменения и без сравнения.

Как же тогда сказать, если было +33°C, а стало +29°C? Оптимальный вариант - *уже не так жарко*. Или можно - *жара (чуть) спала*. Можно сравнить - *стало менее жарко*, но не сильно звучит, хотя в книгах встречается.

Между "потеплело" и "похолодало" не должно быть разницы в "обязательных мыслях". Это ведь две стороны одной медали, противоположности, как минус и плюс в математике. "Потеплело" тоже подразумевает наличие тепла.

Разница разве что с точки зрения физики - холодать (уменьшаться температура) может до полной остановки движения молекул (-273,15 °С), а теплеть (повышаться температура) может условно до бесконечности - хотя учёные примерно подсчитали верхнюю границу, но число там очень большое.

Comment: В каких таких обязательных мыслях?)

Comment: "И действительно ли "холоднее" нейтральнее (и уместнее), чем "прохладнее", вызывающее **обязательные мысли**, что уже довольно прохладно (смотрите начало второго абзаца)?" — цитата из вопроса. А потом спрашивается про разницу между похолоданием и потеплением в этом аспекте.

Comment: Всё равно фразы не понял.(

Comment: Какой фразы? Это же вы писали про "вызывающее обязательные мысли". Просто сослался на эту фразу.

Comment: Да я понял уже, что вы на мою сослались, но всё равно не понимаю, что значит "не должно быть разницы в обязательных мыслях".

Comment: Это значит, что *похолодало* подразумевает наличие холода, *стало прохладнее* - наличие прохлады, а *потеплело* - наличие тепла. То есть везде такие "обязательные мысли" присутствуют, разницы нет.